# Jquery Multiple classes with same name, different backgrounds at random

Tags: jquery, css, image, background

The title should say it all really, I have 4 IMAGES, 5 classes all named the same. The images apply to the first 4 classes (again they are the same class names), the 5th does not add the image (see attached image). I want the images to appear random on each class. I also want the images to be random. 
[image: 5th one does not have a background]

Here is my code.

```
$("table.catalogFooterArea").css("background", function(i) {
  return [
   "url(Custom/themes/pilot/css/images/catItemFoot.png)",
   "url(Custom/themes/pilot/css/images/catItemFoot2.png)",
   "url(Custom/themes/pilot/css/images/catItemFoot3.png)",
   "url(Custom/themes/pilot/css/images/catItemFoot4.png)"][i];
});
```

Comment: Random what? To get a random index you need Math.floor(Math.random()*imageArray.length)

Comment: Pardon, I want this to put a random background image on each table.catalogFooterArea I did math.random but it put the same img on all of the classes table.catalogFooterArea this method worked, but will only add the image to the first 4 table.catalogFooterArea. What I am trying to do, is add at random a image to the background of each of the table.catalogFooterArea.

Comment: Then use .each and test if the random image has already been taken

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = ['catItemFoot.png', 'catItemFoot2.png', 'catItemFoot3.png', 'catItemFoot4.png'];

$("table.catalogFooterArea").each(function(){
  $(this).css({'background' : 'url(custom/themes/pilot/css/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'})
   });
```

That worked thanks mplungjan forgot about using .each!